# Can't Publish Table Changes in Azure Data Studio: Table Designer Error

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

After making changes to a table using table designer I get these errors.
I googled it alot over the last few months.. couldn't find anything that helped.

> Table schema validation failed with error: One or more errors occured during validation.
>
> 1. Must declare the variable or parameter "@FileName"
> 2. Must declare the variable or parameter "@FileName"
> 3. Object [dbo].[tblFilelist] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 4. Object [dbo].[tblFileList] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 5. Object [dbo].[quMMSScoreCard] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 6. Object [dbo].[quMMSScorecard] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 7. Object [dbo].[PK_tblFilelist] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 8. Object [dbo].[PK_tblFileList] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 9. Object [dbo].[FillRateWorksheet].[idxheaderId] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.
> 10. Object [dbo].[FillRateWorksheet].[idxHeaderID] doesn't have a unique name when case is ignored.

[image]

Comment: This reads more like a bug report than anything. Honestly, I always suggest you learn the code to do that changes, rather than relying on (often) buggy/quirky/feature lacking designers.

Comment: I am able to do change the table and publish it in azure data studio 1.47.1 version